# Mist looking for wrong Geth version

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I use geth to run an ethereum node and mist to compile contract. Allways have worked fine until I change to the next version of Geth. Now I use version 1.7.3.

The problem is that Mist is still looking for version 1.7.2

How can I tell mist to look for version 1.7.3?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/wiki#start-the-node-manually) you should try to put your updated geth to: `cd %APPDATA%\Mist\binaries\geth`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my MacBook Pro OS x Sierra.

I had to run Geth 1.7.3 from the terminal with this command

```
/Users/andrewhack/Downloads/geth-darwin/geth  --fast --cache=2048
```

The directory will be different as it is where you download & unpack Geth 1.7.3

Once i had Geth running manually, i started up my Mist Wallet, it ignored Geth 1.7.2 the tick was not made when i checked. I had to do this for a couple of hours over a number of weeks. I did not let it run continuously.

My Mist Wallet eventually synced and i could see my Ethereum in my wallet, i did not delete my chaindata before running Geth 1.7.2 manually from terminal.

It is definitely a bug in Mist Wallet & hopefully that will get fixed in a update, so this is just a work around or temporary fix.

Have faith & stick with this method to the end, if this helps resolve your issue & get back your Ethereum that you thought was lost.

Consider donating a small percentage to disabled war veteran 0x9CBFf64255094129800c6Ea6d1f575e0C7B75DAf